# Get data from custom customize field

Tags: php, wordpress

I've setup new fields below, there's two types for images and text how can I call it now on a php file I'm assuming there's a function for it.
I'm able to access the fields on the theme > customize and add data to it but now I want to paste on a template.

```
$wp_customize->add_section('travel_video', array(
    'priority'    => 16,
    'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
    'title'       => __('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; - Featured Videos', 'travel-lite'),
    'description' => ''
));

$wp_customize->add_setting('travel[fpvideo]', array(
    'default'           => __('Title 1', 'travel-lite'),
    'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_textarea',
    'type'              => 'option'
));

$wp_customize->add_control('travel_fpvideo' , array(
    'label'      => __('Title 1', 'travel-lite'),
    'section'    => 'travel_video',
    'settings'   => 'travel[fpvideo]'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code,you can look for reference [customizer](http://ttps://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_register)

```
function mytheme_customize_register($wp_customize) {
    $wp_customize->add_section('travel_video', array(
        'priority' => 16,
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'title' => __('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; - Featured Videos', 'travel-lite'),
        'description' => ''
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting('travel[fpvideo]', array(
        'default' => __('Title 1', 'travel-lite'),
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_textarea',
        'type' => 'option'
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('travel_fpvideo', array(
        'label' => __('Title 1', 'travel-lite'),
        'section' => 'travel_video',
        'settings' => 'travel[fpvideo]'
    ));
}

add_action('customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register');
```

Comment: thanks I'm actually able to view the fields on theme > customize since I added them to a pre existing theme but I'd actually like to paste them on a template

Comment: Use get_theme_mode('key_of_field'), @SamuelMuiruri